# Converting lots of images in pdf-format to jpg-format

Tags: pdf, convert

More precisely: Given a folder containing images in pdf-format (each of which has a name of the form NAME.pdf, with NAME being composed of several words separated by spaces),
how do I batch convert the images to jpg-format *and* preserve their names in the form NAME.jpg ?
(Using pdftoppm as indicated in "How to convert a .pdf file into a folder of images?"
seems rather complicated, since it requires treating each image separately.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `convert` from `imagemagick` to convert a PDF into an image.

To install it, use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

---

To convert all PDFs in a directory, go to that directory and run the following command:

```
for i in *.pdf; do convert "$i" "${i%.*}.jpg"; done
```

<sub>[ImageMagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) | [Bash string manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664740/extract-file-basename-without-path-and-extension-in-bash)</sub>

Comment: That will not work for files with spaces in the name ("NAME being composed of several words separated by spaces). You have to quote the variables.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect this.