# Batch convert multiple screenshots in PNG to JPG

Tags: convert, image-processing, png

I have multiple screenshots in PNG format to print but cannot get them converted to JPG on my Galaxy S6 phone.

How can I convert multiple PNG screenshots to JPG photos so I can print them on a photo website?

Comment: GIMP will do the trick

Answer (score 4):

### [imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/)

You can use [`mogrify`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) (or [`convert`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)) from `imagemagick`

To install it, use the following command:

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```

Then go to the folder with the PNGs and:

```
mogrify -format jpg *.png
```

#### Notes

- You could also `rm *.png`
- Also useful to convert all to a single PDF: `mogrify *.jpg naughtyphotos.pdf`
- Format shouldn't be an impediment to print your photos.
- You may also want to [remove all the EXIF metadata content](https://askubuntu.com/a/968598/349837).
- Another way [is with `ufraw-batch`](https://askubuntu.com/a/605752/349837)
- Related: [Converting lots of images in pdf-format to jpg-format](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352423/converting-lots-of-images-in-pdf-format-to-jpg-format)